# How to restart FreeBSD host from Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

I use Zabbix 3.4.4 and I have Host group of FreeBSD-11 hosts. How can I restart all hosts from this host group? Do I need zabbix agent for every FreeBSD host necessarily ?

Answer (score 0):

With Zabbix agent you can use [remote commands](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command) to do so. Agent is usually a good idea in any case as it allows easy collection of a lot of metrics.

Without agent, you would probably have to resort to SSH remote commands, described in the same page or if you have access to the hardware, even the [IPMI commands](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command#ipmi_remote_commands).